# Google cloud Instance ruby - Is the server running on host "" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to deploy a ruby app on google cloud. I am getting this error when I am running rake `db:migrate`.

> Is the server running on host "###.###.#.###" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

I have checked other answers and people have suggested

- **postgresql.conf** - changing: `listen_address = '*'`
- **pg_hba.conf** - adding:

  ```
  # IPv4 remote connections (all users and IP addresses):
  host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0                md5
  ```
- **postgresql.conf** - checking: port is 5432.

None of these have solved the issue. Does anyone have any other ideas? I am new to google cloud and am not sure what code I could post to help. If any code would help you solve the issue, please comment and I will post it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error you are getting, ensure that there are no firewalls, such as `iptables` or [Google Cloud network properties](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking#network_properties) without port `5432` opened that are keeping your server system from even establishing a connection for a given port.